# Controlling momentary switch controlled machine with programmable socket

Tags: switches

I'm trying to control a coffee machine with a programmable socket to make it switch-on in the morning (aah, love coffee smell while still on bed)

The problem is the machine is controlled by a momentary push-button as a toggle switch so obviously I can't set it on with no power and have it automatically switch on when the socket is on.

Do any of you have any good idea on what kind of circuit I could use to operate the switch only the moment the power goes on?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't want to take the brewer apart.

1. Tape on the button.
2. Arduino with a servo powered off the same socket as the brewer
3. Solenoid which pushes the button or letting off an impact device, like a steel ball rolling down a ramp to the button. It will look like something from a Spielberg movie...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can power on the module with a relay in the morning. I have this circuit designed for same purpose. Once the machine is powered, below circuit will generate a short pulse. It is a negative pulse at the moment. Depending on your moment switch you can add another transistor at the output to make it positive pulse.

[image]